# Laravel 8 withSum relation default value 0

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Will laravel 8's withSum function supports default value?

```
use App\Models\Post;
 
$posts = Post::withSum('comments', 'votes')->get();
```

In this relation laravel returns 'comments_sum_votes' as null if a 'post' has no 'comments'.Can we set it to return 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just bumped into this.

While an eloquent accessor may work in certain situations, doing ORDER BY or GROUP BY on this column still wouldn't return correct results (because the database query would still return null when no records are found).

Alternatively, you could do COALESCE yourself like so, which is more efficient:

```
$post = Post::query()
    ->withSum([
    'comments' => fn ($query) => $query->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(votes), 0)')),
], 'votes')
    ->get();
```

[Ref](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/withsum-returns-null-instead-of-0)

Comment: That is clever but it doesn't work if you have no votes, then it will return null instead of 0.